# Keep an instance variable on a latter iteration on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, instagram, omniauth

I have a problem which I haven't been able to find the answer for quite some time...

I'm implementing Instagram login using the omniauth gem, however there's a limit on the info that instagram provides such as the email or the age of a user which I particularly need for this web app.

So what I'm trying to do is to get all possible data from instagram and then redirect the user to another view where I can have provided both age and email.

By doing so I'm using two controllers which I need to share the user's data, however when the second controller method needs to use this variable's contents, the var is set to Nil and there's no method I can use to rebuild the data as it hasn't been actually saved to the database.

Here's some code:

```
class SomeOAuthController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

...

#This controller retrieves the oauth data and has a view to retrieve all the extra data.
def instagram 
   @user_ig = User.from_omniauth_instagram(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  if @user_ig.provider != :instagram.to_s
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end

#Método para completar el registro de instagram
def create_instagram_user

  p 'entro a create_instagram_user'
  p @user_ig
  #@user_ig.adult = params[:user][:adult]
  #@user_ig.email = params[:user][:email]

end

...
```

Here is the view for the instagram method:

```
<%= form_for(@user_ig, url: {action: :create_instagram_user}) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :adult %>
    <%= f.check_box :adult %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit t('bulula.session.sign_up') %>
  </div>
```

So, wrapping it up:

**Problem**

I need to keep not Nil the variable filled in the `instagram` method for it to be used in the `create_instagram_user` method which will be called by submitting the `instagram` view button without saving any content to the database.

**Workaround solution**

In case I can't find any solution here I was hoping to create a temp database table where I can save the incomplete content retrieved from instagram and move it along with the data the user provides from the form and create a new user.

Nonetheless this seems a bit tricky and I'm not fully comfortable with it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is make use of `cookies` in storing the info that is needed and retrieving it for later use, as follows:

```
class SomeOAuthController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def instagram 
        @user_ig = User.from_omniauth_instagram(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user_ig.provider != :instagram.to_s
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            # store the values that you would need in the subsequent request
            cookies[:instagram] = {
                key1: @user_ig.value1,
                key2: @user_ig.value2,
                key3: @user_ig.value3,
            }
        end
    end

    def create_instagram_user
        @user_ig = {}
        @user_ig['key1'] = cookies[:instagram][:key1]
        @user_ig['key2'] = cookies[:instagram][:key2]
        @user_ig['key3'] = cookies[:instagram][:key3]
        @user_ig['adult'] = params[:user][:adult]
        @user_ig['email'] = params[:user][:email]
        # create instagram user with the @user_ig info
        cookies.delete(:instagram) # some housekeeping
    end
end
```

In place of `cookies[:instagram]`, you could also use `cookies.signed[:instagram]` or `cookies.encrypted[:instagram]` to be more secure.

Review [Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) for more info on use the use of `cookies`.

Comment: Sir, I'm afraid 'key1', 'key2' and 'key3' prevent the cookie from being saved